# Ansible 2.13 yum module - requires minimum version of target python of 2.7 or 3.5. But I already have that

Tags: python, ansible, interpreter

I have an Ansible (2.13) machine targeting a remote centOS 6 with Python 3.6.

Remote machine has python3.6 installed and variables are set like this:

$ ansible-inventory --host centos-6-vm

```
{
    "ansible_private_key_file": "~/.ssh/id_rsa",
    "ansible_python_interpreter": "/usr/bin/python3.6",
    "ansible_user": "daniel"
}
```

Ansible can ping, setup and gather facts from target successfully.

But when trying to run the `yum` module, I get an error as if my server doesn't have Python 3.6

This is my playbook

```yaml
---
- name: Deploy Services
  hosts: centos-6-vm
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

    - name: Show python interpreter
      debug:
        var: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - ansible_python_interpreter
        - ansible_python_version

    - name: Patch
      become: true
      yum:
        name: "*"
        security: true
        state: latest
        update_cache: true
```

The first task is just to confirm that Ansible is recognizing Python versions. And the result is success.

```
ok: [centos-6-vm] => (item=ansible_python_interpreter) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "ansible_python_interpreter": "/usr/bin/python3.6",
    "item": "ansible_python_interpreter"
}
ok: [centos-6-vm] => (item=ansible_python_version) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "ansible_python_version": "3.6.6",
    "item": "ansible_python_version"
}
```

But when it gets in the module, it gets an error saying no Python3.

```
TASK [Patch] ***********************************************************************************************************
fatal: [centos-6-vm]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "ansible-core requires a minimum of Python2 version 2.7 or Python3 version 3.5. Current version: 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug 18 2016, 15:13:37) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)]"}
```

Any idea how can I approach that?

Comment: I believe that Ansible is looking for your local Python installation (`/usr/bin/python`) to run `ansible-core`. Maybe try using a virtual environment to run Ansible - this is the recommended way to run Ansible.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. But Im actually running a venv on ansible machine already with python 3.9. In fact I think its a pre requisite to ansible 2.13. So thats the reason I think the problem is not on localhost. $ python --version
Python 3.9.13

Comment: Have you tried running that playbook on the localhost? `ansible-playbook ... localhost --check`

Comment: The version of Python on your *local* machine isn't the problem. Ansible needs a compatible version of Python on the *remote* machine, and it's unlikely that CentOS 6 has that in the standard location. You will need to (a) install a more recent version of Python, and then (b) specify a path to that Python using the `ansible_python_interpreter` variable when connecting to that host.

Comment: Hi Rafael, when I check localhost i dont get a problem with Python. I only get a problem with yum module. Because my ansible host is ubuntu. only my target is centos

Comment: Hi Larsks. Thats what im doing. You are right. centos6 doesnt have have 2.7 nor python3 by default. But I have installed and configure interpreter ansible_python_interpreter: "/usr/bin/python3.6". The first tasks "Show python interpreter" is only to confirm that

Comment: Just complementing the previous information the ansible_python_interpreter is the in host_vars for centos-6-vm. When I remove that the ansible cannot even ping the target. But setting ansible_python_interpreter i can successfully execute most tasks, but getting an error here (yum)

Answer (score 3):

It’s a compatibility mismatch between Ansible 2.13 and the yum module on the rhel6-based systems.

I got this insight above from Martz on another platform, and I don’t know how to give proper credits here, If I learn I`ll edit the post later.

So as a solution I used Ansible when condition with *ansible_distribution_major_version == 6* to determine if the server is release 6 and used the **command module** passing the command “yum update -y”.
And I kept the Ansible **yum module** for *ansible_distribution_major_version >=7*

Another option would be to downgrade Ansible to 2.12 which I discarded

Comment: Thanks, just a note to say I had to include an `int`filter on the major version parameter in order to not get an error on the conditional, like `when: ansible_distribution_major_version|int >= 7`